# Unexpected macro value when lambda is used

Tags: c++, lambda, macros

Say I have 3 classes; Main class, First class and Second class.

In class First and class Second I define a MACRO(name - `CLASS_NAME`), the purpose of the macro is that in every class I redefine the macro to className or anything else to use that macro in it's functions.

The structure of the code is as follows

- Class First, Second and Main all have macro `CLASS_NAME` with their
  class name(e.g. "first", "second", "main") as value.
- Class Second includes First and overwrites this macro value and
  additionally declares another macro `PRINT_CLASS_NAME` which just
  prints the `CLASS_NAME` macro.
- Class First does not have this `PRINT_CLASS_NAME` macro, so I have
  declared a function pointer and set it's value from Main class with a
  lambda.
- Class Main includes both First and Second and redefines macro `CLASS_NAME`. To check the output please see the the Main.cpp file

Class First - Header file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#undef CLASS_NAME 
#define CLASS_NAME "first"

class First
{
public:
    First();
    ~First();

    // simple class that prints the value of CLASS_NAME
    void printClassName();
    // sets the function pointer
    void setPrintClassName(std::function<void()> inFunctionPointer);
    // The function pointer that holds the lambda to show CLASS_NAME's value
    std::function<void()> mPrintClassFromSecond;
};
```

Class First - Source file

```
#include "First.h"

First::First()
{
    std::cout << "Class First : Constructor" << "\n";
}
First::~First()
{
}

void First::printClassName()
{
    std::cout << "Class name from function : " << CLASS_NAME << "\n";
}

void First::setPrintClassName(std::function<void()> inFunctionPointer)
{
    mPrintClassFromSecond = inFunctionPointer;
}
```

Class Second - Header file

```
#pragma once
#include "First.h"
#include <functional>

#undef CLASS_NAME
#define CLASS_NAME "second"

#define PRINT_CLASS_NAME std::cout << "Class name from Macros: " << CLASS_NAME << "\n"

class Second
{
public:
    Second();
    ~Second();
};
```

Class Second - Source file

```
#include "Second.h"

Second::Second()
{
    std::cout << "Class Second : Constructor" << "\n";
    PRINT_CLASS_NAME;
}
Second::~Second()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
// MacrosWithFunctionPointerProblem.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
// after including First.h the CLASS_NAME macro value for this class is "first"
#include "First.h"
// after including Second.h the CLASS_NAME macro value for this class is "second"
#include "Second.h"

// after this the CLASS_NAME macro value for this class is "main"
#undef CLASS_NAME
#define CLASS_NAME "main"

int main()
{
    First _first;
    // outputs CLASS_NAME value "first" which is expected
    _first.printClassName();
    // sets lambda to use macro PRINT_CLASS_NAME
    _first.setPrintClassName([](){ PRINT_CLASS_NAME; });
    // outputs CLASS_NAME value "main" which was not expected by me
    _first.mPrintClassFromSecond();

    // outputs CLASS_NAME value "first" which is expected
    Second _second;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Class First : Constructor
Class name from function : first
Class name from Macros: main
Class Second : Constructor
Class name from Macros: second
```

**Question:** Whey I am getting "main" for the value of macro `CLASS_NAME` instead of "first". How can I avoid getting "main" as the value of `CLASS_NAME` and get "first" as value?

**PS:** I tried to minimize the problem as much as possible, so if i left any important detail that might help you understand the problem better please ask it in comments.

Comment: The lambda is a red herring, you could see the same behaviour of macros by changing that line to `PRINT_CLASS_NAME;`

Comment: sorry I did not understand, changing which line to PRINT_CLASS_NAME;?

Comment: oh! instead of `[](){ PRINT_CLASS_NAME; }` this if we have written only `PRINT_CLASS_NAME;` this, it would have same, right?

Comment: `[](){ PRINT_CLASS_NAME; }` is a lambda that prints "main". So when you call it, it prints "main".  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: @immibis Bui I am calling the function pointer which was set to class `First` , and `First` has macro value "first". I thought it will out the value "first'. To get my expected output what should be done?

Comment: Why are you using macros for this, macros only exist during the preprocessing stage, classes know nothing about them so your statement "First has macro" is nonsense. If you want class specific behaviors, use C++, instead of the preprocessor.

Comment: @kfsone I agree with you, but the project I am working on is quite old and are done this way. Changing it is not feasible. Thus the problem and a search of a workaround

Comment: May I know why this question got down voted?

Comment: @sami1592 To get your expected output you could pass the class name as an argument to the lambda. Or you could put `cout << "Class name from Macros: first" << endl;` inside the lambda.

Comment: @sami1592 Possibly because it indicates that you don't understand macros very well and this is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 2):

MACRO is text substitution without scope, so in

```
_first.setPrintClassName([](){ PRINT_CLASS_NAME; });
```

`PRINT_CLASS_NAME` becomes `std::cout << "Class name from Macros: " << CLASS_NAME << "\n"`

and `CLASS_NAME` here has been (re)defined as `"main"`.

Comment: but it is set to a function pointer of `First` , shouldn't it take the value of class `First` 's macro value? And what role the function pointer play here? A detailed answer would be so much helpful. TIA

Comment: @sami1592 A) no and B) none at all.

Comment: @sami1592: "text substitution without scope" really says it all.

Comment: @Jarod42 How can I avoid getting "main" as the value of CLASS_NAME and get "first" as value instead?

Comment: @sami1592 By using CLASS_NAME within the file `first.cpp` (or whatever your filename is) it will have the value "first".